# Block a specific page not the whole file from the host file

Tags: windows, internet, browser, hosts, hosts-file

Is there a way to block a specific page not the whole website from the host file. For example:

Instead of:

```
127.0.0.1 www.reddit.com
```

I want to block only:

```
127.0.0.1 www.reddit.com/r/Futurology
```

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: PS: If you want to block specifc pages, a [web] proxy might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is there a way to block a specific page not the whole website from the host file?

- Short answer: No
- Longer answer:

  A host file is a text file that contains lines of text consisting of an IP address in the first text field followed by one or more hostnames.

  A [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname), by definition, does not include directory names that map to specific pages.

Comment: Darn. 42 seconds faster. :)

Comment: @Hennes lol. Have an upvote for coming a close second :)

Answer (score 2):

No. The host file points to hosts.

It does not point to specific protocols (like http) or even sub parts of that.